# Stop Visual Studio from inserting code inside region

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use the Designer to create Windows Forms. All is working fine, but when I add some events (by double-clicking on a button), Visual Studio generates the method in the partial class of the form. This is fine, but the generated method is a big section of accessory. It's really annoying to move the code outside the section each time. When I say section, I mean a part of the code with `#Region`   and   `#endRegion`  before and after, and the generated code is inserted into the section.

I tried to cut the section before and paste it after. I tried to cut the section, add an event, and then paste the section at another place. But each time, Visual Studio restart generating the code inside the section...

How can I force Visual Studio to insert the code at the bottom?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

Comment: This isn't just a C# issue. I run into this all the time when working with the Windows Forms designer on my VB.NET projects.

Comment: Weird, no repro for me. The Click method is generated in the partial class without any other code (except the `Form` constructor) or `#region` directives. Of course the assignment of the method to the Click event is in the other partial class (in `Form1.Designer.cs`) inside the region: `#region Windows Form Designer generated code`. But it doesn't sound like that's what you're talking about.

Comment: I mean I have already a section with code, and there is no way to add events without having Visual Studio putting it at the same place inside the section...

Comment: Are you talking about the line that subscribes a method to an event?

Comment: I'm talking about the method added in the partial class, where I can put the code related to the action.

Comment: not in the .Designer.cs